# grouping by aggregated (summed) double produces inconsistent results in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pivot, rounding, aggregation

I'm seeing some inconsistent behavior with Scala and Spark 2.0 around aggregating doubles then grouping by the aggregated value. This only occurs in cluster mode and I believe it has something to do with the order in which the doubles are summed producing a slightly different number. After the initial aggreation, I pivot the results and group by the summed value. Sometimes see 1 row, sometimes 2 rows based on the value changing slightly at the 20th decimal place or so. I can't show a full example, but here is a simplified/contrived version in the REPL which behaves correctly but shows what I'm trying to do:

```
scala> val df = List((1, "a", 27577661.013638947), (1, "a", 37577661.013538947)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+---+---+--------------------+
|  a|  b|                   c|
+---+---+--------------------+
|  1|  a|2.7577661013638947E7|
|  1|  a| 3.757766101353895E7|
+---+---+--------------------+

scala> val grouped = df.groupBy("a", "b").agg(sum("c").as("c"))
grouped: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> grouped.show
+---+---+------------------+
|  a|  b|                 c|
+---+---+------------------+
|  1|  a|6.51553220271779E7|
+---+---+------------------+


scala> val pivoted = grouped.groupBy("c").pivot("a").agg(first("b"))
pivoted: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c: double, 1: string]

scala> pivoted.show
+------------------+---+
|                 c|  1|
+------------------+---+
|6.51553220271779E7|  a|
+------------------+---+
```

The problem shows up after the pivot where I will see 2 rows here instead of the expected single row.

Is this expected? A bug? Any workarounds? I've tried using BigDecimal vs double, rounding, UDF vs column expression, and nothing helps so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected:

- Floating point arithmetics is [not associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Order of aggregations in Spark is non-deterministic and so is the result.
- Floating are not a good choice for grouping keys. They have no meaningful equality (typically you check if difference is smaller than a machine precision). In Spark, where aggregations are based on hashes, you cannot even use this notion of equality.

Comment: A potential workaround might be to multiply c by some multiple of 10 (to match your desired precision) then round it to an integer, and then group by it.